# Possible to save cookies into my browser without using "Set-Cookie" command in the HTTP header?

Tags: javascript, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I am automating the login process of a website but I find after I log into the portal, the XHR(XMLHttpRequest) my browser sends out contains a cookie named "pppp"... But I checked all the http communication before that; failed to find this "pppp" in any "Set-Cookie" command in HTTP response headers...

Comment: Cookies can be set with javascript also

Comment: If you have the access of the server side then you can check for this syntax `res.cookie()`